Voltage regulator stepping down voltage but not increasing current output?
I have these generic LM2596S buck converter modules.

I'm trying to buck the voltage from a 20V, 400mA solar panel to ~5V, 1A. From what I understand, after efficiency loss, I should be able to get more current on the output after bucking the voltage. I should even have ~3W of headroom. For some reason, the module only "passes through" the available current from the input to the output, and doesn't inversely increase current after it regulates the voltage. I've tested the module with a desk bench power supply set to 20V, 400mA, and after bucking the voltage to ~5V, the maximum current that the buck outputs is the limit set on the desk bench power supply. When I increase the desk bench power supply current limit, the buck converter output matches/ parallels the that current limit. I did the same test with a different, less suitable buck converter that gets hot when doing its job (Mini 360 Buck Converter), and it seems to work just fine. But I'm stumped as to why the LM2596S is stealing my watts.
Any ideas as to:

Why is this happening?

Any fix to get the expected behavior while using the LM2596S module?



One test was a short, the other a dc motor.

Please measure your solar panel voltage during your load test.

If energy is getting lost somewhere, it should be converted to heat. So you could try checking what part is getting hot when you are losing 15 W in the conversion.

How did you test the maximum current output?

The bench supply test seems to indicate that something is wrong with either the module or your test methods.
Assuming we can rule out the latter, perhaps something is wrong such as the inductor being shorted (perhaps underneath). The inductor does look slightly misaligned, not necessarily a problem in itself, but usually SMT parts self-align on the pads.


If the output is 5V 1A, or 5W, it does mean that ideally the same 5W is taken by the input, so at 20V, the input is 0.25A, but only on average. As the output voltage is only 25% of the input, it needs to take the energy needed in quarter of the time. Basically, it needs to charge the inductor to 1A for 1A output, so it will take 1A in at 20V but for 25% of the time of switching period.

no, not really the fault of the module, but how you use it. That's how switch mode supplies work. You need a big hefty bulk capacitor or LC filter before the module, so that voltage does not drop too much while the module takes a short pulse of 1A.



The module already has 220µF input capacitor, and a lab power supply will have its own output capacitors. It is very unlikely that the 1.7 µs pulses (at 25% duty 150 kHz) would be triggering the power supply current limiter.

The module appears to be deficient in some way.
If it is really wasting 6 W of energy somewhere (20 V 400 mA in, 5 V 400 mA out), something should be getting very hot.
Alternatively it may be that the converter is entering some kind of protection mode. What Justme says about switching mode converters needing good input and output bypassing capacitors is true.
The manufacturer of this module seems to have cheaped out by not installing any ceramic capacitors. The high ESR of the electrolytic capacitors will increase the ripple voltage.
You could try installing ceramic capacitors in these locations. For example 50 V 10 µF 1210 should fit:

